# Create a process and tell it to sleep?

Tags: c, unix, process, fork, sleep

What's the right way to tell a specific process to sleep?
I don't fully understand how to control the different processes I create..

I'm trying to make two processes that sleep for 2 and 3 seconds. When process 1 has slept for 2 seconds, and process 2 is still sleeping I want process 3 to start sleeping. But how do I tell a process to sleep? Or don't I?

```
int main(void)
{
    pid_t p1 = fork();
    pid_t p2 = fork();
    pid_t p3 = fork();

    //make p1 sleep(2) and p2 sleep(3)
    waitpid(p1, NULL, 0); //waiting for p1 to terminate
    //make p3 sleep(2);
}
```

As you can see I don't understand how to handle processes, or what they really are. I kind of see them as objects, but I'm guessing that's wrong.. I've tried reading some stuff about it, but they are all over 9000 pages PDF's.. A simple explanation of what I should see them as would be appreciated. And yes, this is school-material, but no, it's not an assignment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with [`man fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) which is slightly shorter than 9000 pages. The main thing is that successful `fork` returns *two times*: it returns 0 to the child process and the child's PID to the parent process. It's typically used like this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid<0) { /* error while forking */
};
if (!pid) { /* code for child */
  play();
  whine();
  sleep();
  exit(0);
} else { /* code for parent */
  grunt();
  waitpid(...);
}
```

You don't normally *tell* the child process to do this and that, you just add code doing it to the appropriate `if` branch.

In your example, if all forks are successful, you end up with **8** processes:

1. First fork creates a new process, `p1` gets 0 in the new process and some pid in the parent.
2. Second fork is called both in the original parent and in the child, adding 2 processes to the picture.
   `p2` gets 0 in all "grandchildren" and two different pids in 2 processes existing before step 2.
3. Third fork is called in **four** different processes, adding four other processes to the picture.

Answer (score 5):

You could send it a `SIGSTOP` and then a `SIGCONT` I think.

```
kill(p1, SIGSTOP);
```

Alternatively and more sanely, since you're only forking and thus have complete controll over the code, you could handle the paths:

```
if (in_child_1)
    sleep(..);
```

---

As a side note, in your code more processes are created than you expect. The thing is once `p1` is created it **starts executing from that point, in parallel with its parent**. And so on.

Comment: So it's not possible to let a child-process `sleep(i)` while other child-processes work? And yes, I noticed earlier that they were kind of exponentially coming at me, why is that? I guess I'll have to read up on fork..